# PHP Regular Expression. Check if String contains ONLY letters

Tags: php, regex, string

In PHP, how do I check if a String contains only letters?  I want to write an if statement that will return false if there is (white space, number, symbol) or anything else other than `a-z` and `A-Z`.

My string must contain ONLY letters.

I thought I could do it this way, but I'm doing it wrong:

```
if( ereg("[a-zA-Z]+", $myString))
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

How do I find out if `myString` contains only letters?

Comment: That's not Java. You probably meant PHP.

Comment: Why regex? `ctype_alpha($myString);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never heard of `ereg`, but I'd guess that it will match on substrings.

In that case, you want to include anchors on either end of your regexp so as to force a match on the whole string:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Also, you could simplify your function to read

```
return ereg("^[a-zA-Z]+$", $myString);
```

because the `if` to return `true` or `false` from what's already a boolean is redundant.

---

Alternatively, you could match on any character that's *not* a letter, and return the complement of the result:

```
return !ereg("[^a-zA-Z]", $myString);
```

Note the `^` at the beginning of the character set, which inverts it. Also note that you no longer need the `+` after it, as a single "bad" character will cause a match.

---

Finally... this advice is for Java because you have a <kbd>Java</kbd> tag on your question. But the `$` in `$myString` makes it look like you're dealing with, maybe Perl or PHP? Some clarification might help.

Comment: Note that `ereg` as been deprecated as of PHP 5.3. Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead

Answer (score 10):

Yeah this works fine. Thanks

```
if(myString.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks like `PHP`. It would return `true` if the string has a letter in it. To make sure the string has **only** letters you need to use the start and end **anchors**:

In `Java` you can make use of the `matches` method of the `String` class:

```
boolean hasOnlyLetters(String str) {
   return str.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
}
```

In `PHP` the function `ereg` is **deprecated** now. You need to use the `preg_match` as replacement. The `PHP` equivalent of the above function is:

```
function hasOnlyLetters($str) {
   return preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i',$str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be different and use [`Character.isLetter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) definition of what is a letter.

```
if (myString.matches("\\p{javaLetter}*"))
```

Note that this matches more than just `[A-Za-z]*`.

> A character is considered to be a letter if its general category type, provided by `Character.getType(ch)`, is any of the following: UPPERCASE_LETTER, LOWERCASE_LETTER, TITLECASE_LETTER, MODIFIER_LETTER, OTHER_LETTER
>
> Not all letters have case. Many characters are letters but are neither uppercase nor lowercase nor titlecase.

The `\p{javaXXX}` character classes is defined in [`Pattern` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#jcc).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try checking if it contains anything other than letters: [^A-Za-z]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do a "is ALL characters of a given type" is to check if ANY character is NOT of the type.

So if \W denotes a non-character, then just check for one of those.

Comment: True in general, but in Java it's usually easier to do it the other way because of the implicit anchoring of the `matches()` method. So it's `s.matches("\\w+")` vs `!s.matches(".*\\W.*")`